Multiple MFRC522 RFID readers on Raspi Zero
For university I have to connect multiple RFID readers to my raspi. Ideally 8 at a time. However after weeks of testing I have not managed to make it work. I figured out that the setmode GPIO.BOARD allows me to talk to all the pins I want and set them high for example. But I have been unable to read any data from a RFID reader other then when the SDA is connected to pin 24. Any other pin even when declared in the script does not seem to work. I tried the script from Alex Berliner in this post, but without any luck. here
This is my current script which also does not seem to be working:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import MFRC522
import spidev
import time
 
class RFIDReader:
    def __init__(self, rst_pin, cs_pin, spi_bus=0, spi_device=0):
        self.rst_pin = rst_pin
        self.cs_pin = cs_pin
        self.spi_bus = spi_bus
        self.spi_device = spi_device
        GPIO.setup(rst_pin, GPIO.OUT)
        print(rst_pin)
        self.mfrc522 = MFRC522(self.spi_bus, self.spi_device, self.rst_pin, self.cs_pin)
 
    def read(self):
        print("reading: rst_pin")
        (status, TagType) = self.mfrc522.MFRC522_Request(self.mfrc522.PICC_REQIDL)
        if status == self.mfrc522.MI_OK:
            (status, uid) = self.mfrc522.MFRC522_Anticoll()
            if status == self.mfrc522.MI_OK:
                uid_str = ".".join([str(i) for i in uid])
                print(uid_str)
                return uid_str
        return None
 
# Setup GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
 
# Initialize readers
reader1 = RFIDReader(rst_pin=24, cs_pin=0)  # CE0
reader2 = RFIDReader(rst_pin=26, cs_pin=1)  # CE1
 
try:
    while True:
        uid1 = reader1.read()
        if uid1:
            print(f"Reader 1 detected UID: {uid1}")
 
        uid2 = reader2.read()
        if uid2:
            print(f"Reader 2 detected UID: {uid2}")
 
        time.sleep(0.1)
 
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()

I have another test script which also only reads from pin 24:
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522  

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  

import signal  

import spidev  

import sys  

import time  

   

class NFC():  

    def __init__(self, bus=0, device=0, spd=1000000):  

        self.reader = SimpleMFRC522()  

        self.close()  

        self.boards = {}  

        self.bus = bus  

        self.device = device  

        self.spd = spd  

   

    def reinit(self):  

        self.reader.READER.spi = spidev.SpiDev()  

        self.reader.READER.spi.open(self.bus, self.device)  

        self.reader.READER.spi.max_speed_hz = self.spd  

        self.reader.READER.MFRC522_Init()  

   

    def close(self):  

        self.reader.READER.spi.close()  

   

    def addBoard(self, rid, pin):  

        self.boards[rid] = pin  

        GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)  

        print(pin)  

        print(self.boards)  

   

    def selectBoard(self, rid):  

        if not rid in self.boards:  

            print("readerid " + rid + " not found")  

            return False  

   

        #for loop_id in self.boards:  

            #GPIO.output(self.boards[loop_id], loop_id == rid)  

        return True  

   

    def read(self, rid):  

        if not self.selectBoard(rid):  

            return None  

        self.reinit()  

        rid, val = self.reader.read_no_block()  

        self.close()  

        return val  

   

    def write(self, rid, value):  

        if not self.selectBoard(rid):  

            return False  

        self.reinit()  

        self.reader.write_no_block(value)  

        self.close()  

        return True  

   

# clean up gpios on ctrl+c  

def signal_handler(sig, frame):  

    GPIO.cleanup()  

    print()  

    sys.exit(0)  

   

def main():  

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)  

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)  

 

    nfc = NFC()  

   

    readers = [  

        # rid, pin  

        ("reader1", 24),  

        ("reader2", 26),  

    ]  

   

    for r in readers:  

        nfc.addBoard(r[0], r[1])  

   

    while True:  

        for r in readers:  

            try:  

                r_name = r[0]  

                if r[1] == 24:  

                    GPIO.output(24, GPIO.LOW)  

                    GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)  

                    print("reading 24")  

                else:  

                    GPIO.output(24, GPIO.HIGH)  

                    GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW)  

                    print("reading 26")  

                data = nfc.read(r_name)  

                if data:  

                    print(f"{r_name}: {data}")  

                else:  

                    print(f"No data from {r_name} {r[1]} detected")  

            except Exception as e:  

                print("e", e)  

   

    GPIO.cleanup()  

   

if __name__ == "__main__":  

    main()   

I would really appreciate any help or hints why this is not working.
Wiring:
First MFRC522    Raspberry Pi Zero
---------------------------
VCC              Pin 1 (3.3V)
GND              Pin 6 (Ground)
RST              Pin 22 (GPIO 25)
SDA              Pin 24 (GPIO 8, CE0)
MOSI             Pin 19 (GPIO 10)
MISO             Pin 21 (GPIO 9)
SCK              Pin 23 (GPIO 11)

Second MFRC522   Raspberry Pi Zero
---------------------------
VCC              Pin 17 (3.3V)
GND              Pin 20 (Ground)
RST              Pin 15 (GPIO 22)
SDA              Pin 26 (GPIO 7, CE1)
MOSI             Pin 19 (GPIO 10)
MISO             Pin 21 (GPIO 9)
SCK              Pin 23 (GPIO 11)


What serial protocol is supported by the MFRC522 modules you are using?  Perhaps it's using SPI or I2C.  You need to edit your question and include that detail.  Once you know the protocol check to see how the Pi Zero supports that protocol to see how many can be connected.

NOTE experienced users use BCM PIN numbers NOT GPIO.BOARD.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/142786/8697 but NOTE SPI0 only supports 2 CS so you would have to implement your own code.

why did you post a picture of the code? ... how is that easier than copy/pasting the code as text?

@Milliways I also provided links to the code. I just couldn't get the formatting right to post the text here so I went for pictures. I am really clueless sadly when it comes to programming Raspberry PIs, especially in connection with RFID.

I figured out the formatting so hopefully that makes it a bit easier to understand and modify. @joan it is SPI I am pretty sure

You are wasting your (and our) time until you are sure you know how the module can communicate with the Pi.  You will then need at least a wiki level understanding of that protocol.  It sounds like you will need to hire a programmer.

This may help regarding multiple SPI devices using Raspberry Pi zero. https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=309400

I have done a lot of additional testing and checking my wiring. Even if I try to just get a RFID sensor working with SDA connected to PIN 26, it does not work. So even with just one device connected no matter what my script looks like it never works on another pin then the CE0 pin aka pin 24. I want to also get the data from pin 26 / CE1 but it never works.
